# import jquery.js in service-workers

Tags: javascript, jquery, service-worker

How can I import jquery in sw.js (https://github.com/mdn/sw-test/blob/gh-pages/sw.js) to trigger event? I tried to use importScripts('path to jquery.js'), but I had the problem : "window isn't defined".

Comment: jQuery (mostly) works by operating on the DOM. [Workers don't have access to the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Service_Worker_API). Are there specific parts of jQuery you want to use in the worker?

Comment: just trigger simple custom event with message that would be listened by another js file.

Comment: You won't be able to do that. Workers have a completely different context than the rest of your code. You'll need to perform [message passing](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/ServiceWorkerMessageEvent) to send data in and out of a worker.

Comment: Ok, thanks! how can I notify another js file from service worker that we are in the offline mode?

Comment: It takes a bit of setup. The end of [this article](https://ole.michelsen.dk/blog/making-an-offline-webapp-with-service-workers.html) explains the process pretty clearly.

Answer (score 0):

Don't import DOM-based libraries like jQuery because service workers don't have DOM so there's no document, XMLHttpRequest, and so on.